# Alamouti scheme and MIMO OFDM model, theoretical or practical concept?

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm, mimo

I am not an expert in signal processing but last week I attended a class of signal processing. We discussed MIMO, OFDM and Alamouti scheme.

On this lecture it was represented a lot of math equations, but wasn’t explained where and it is used in practice.

I asked and got the following answer: “MIMO OFDM is considered a key technology in modern wireless-access communication systems such as 4G or 5G. IT used for high data rate transmission…”

Ok, I can read the same information in all websites about this topic. But we have to understand not all theory in signal processing could be implemented(used) in practice.

1. What the practical use of MIMO OFDM is for me understandable. If I implement a receiver or transmitter or transceiver, my two channels (2 input of antennas) are MIMO system.
2. Alamouti scheme, how does it use in practice?
   I have read some post: [post 1](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/16569/57719), [post 2](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/23023/sfbc-alamouti-scheme-lte)

and I don’t understand if it is usable or it is just theoretical concept?

Comment: WHat do you mean with "Alamouti scheme, how does it use in practice"? I mean, it's MIMO method, and it's implemented just as described.

Comment: And all these are practical things, used in practical systems, if that helps

Comment: (1) MIMO OFDM is widely used in 4G (both LTE and WiMAX), 5G NR, some DVB standards, many recent WIFI standards, etc. Yes MIMO OFDM has many practical use. 
(2) Alamouti scheme is used in LTE. Check transmit diversity transmission mode of LTE E-UTRA.

So, don't worry, keep calm, and learn MIMO OFDM.